# Powershell multiple IF statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am attempting to create a powershell script that can perform the following:

1-Filter by Get-Group on a device via an installed xml file.

2-Only perform the copy function if the group equals Get-Group.

So far, the only thing I've succeeded in having it copy the first or the last file, on an incorrect device. I believe you can only use 2 IF statements a single powershell script? If so, how would I achieve this result I am looking for? I've also tried ElseIF, Else, Switch, and WhatIF with no joy. I have also tried different arguments for the IF statements. -eq, =, -like, and -match. None of which seem to be overly helpful in this situation.

```
$ActiveFilePath = "C:\ProgramData\JKCS\jkupdate\jku.ini"

Function Get-Group
{$Group = ([xml](Get-Content D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml)).'system-information'.'device-group'}

Get-Group
        
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX101Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\101\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
#----------------------------------------------#
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX102Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\102\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
#----------------------------------------------#
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX103Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\103\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
#----------------------------------------------#
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX104Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\104\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
#----------------------------------------------#
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX105Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\105\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
#----------------------------------------------#
If ($Group -eq "XXXXX106Master")
{Copy-Item ".\JKU Files\106\jku.ini" "$ActiveFilePath"}
```

Comment: "I believe you can only use 2 IF statements a single powershell script?" No, that would make it quite terrible to use. It may help if you output `$Group` after calling `Get-Group`. We don't have that file (I think), so we can't really test it for you.

Comment: your variable is scoped to that function, assign it directly to the variable from the outside: `$Group = Get-Group` or use scope assignments.

Comment: I can imagine someone saying something about using a switch statement instead of multiple consecutive if statements, but you certainly don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment to `$Group` during the execution of your `Get-Group` function is not visible to the rest of the script. You could have the function *return* the value instead, and then assign it to `$Group` *outside* the function, like this:

```
Function Get-Group
{return ([xml](Get-Content D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml)).'system-information'.'device-group'}

$Group = Get-Group
```

Or, use a scope modifier in the assignment within the function to make it visible to the whole script:

```
Function Get-Group
{ $Script:Group = ([xml](Get-Content D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml)).'system-information'.'device-group'}

Get-Group
```

Or, if you don't need the function anywhere else, just directly assign `$Group` like this (at Script scope):

```
$Group = ([xml](Get-Content D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml)).'system-information'.'device-group'
```

See the help document "[about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2)" (i.e. run `help about_Scopes`).

Comment: I tried the function code you provided (Thank you!) But it still seems to be throwing the same issues. I also tried it this way, but no joy as well.

`Function Get-Group

{$Group  = ([xml](Get-Content D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml)).'system-information'.'device-group'

Return $Group}

Get-Group`

Comment: @DamenPriddy If none of the snippets in my answer work (and give the same issues), it's likely because of something related to your xml file or something else beyond what you've provided in your question.

Comment: Nice answer! Note that `return` isn't really necessary in PowerShell to output from a function, due to PowerShell's _implict_ output behaviour, which returns (outputs) anything that is not assigned to a variable or redirected or piped into another command.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your Get-Group function somewhat to use

```
function Get-Group {
    # if you load the xml file this way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
    $xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
    $xml.Load('D:\Tools\SystemInformation\SystemInformation.xml')
    $xml.'system-information'.'device-group'
}
```

Then, if all your groups have the same format of "XXXXX" + numeric value + "Master" you could do this:

```
$group     = Get-Group
$subfolder = [regex]::Match($group, '(\d+)Master$').Groups[1].Value
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($subfolder)) {
    $path = Join-Path '.\JKU Files' -ChildPath ('{0}\jku.ini' -f $subfolder)
    Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $ActiveFilePath
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find a matching subfolder name in '$group'"
}
```

Otherwise, if the group names do **not** all have the same format, I would suggest creating a lookup Hashtable where you can match the group name with the path of the ini file

```
$lookup = @{
    'XXXXX101Master'   = 101
    'XYZ102Demo'       = 102
    '103Copy'          = 103
    'X123456789104Huh' = 104
    # etc.
}

$group = Get-Group
if ($lookup.ContainsKey($group)) {
    $subfolder = $lookup[$group]
    $path = Join-Path '.\JKU Files' -ChildPath ('{0}\jku.ini' -f $subfolder)
    Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $ActiveFilePath
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find a matching subfolder name in '$group'"
}
```